# Check if all the substring are included in a string using PHP

Tags: php, regex

let's say I have 2 set of string to check.

```
$string = 12345;
$string2 = 15000;

//string must contain 1,2,3,4,5 to be returned true

if(preg_match('[1-5]',$string) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;}
```

This code works for $string but not for $string2. It returns true too with $string2.
Please help!

Comment: [It does not.](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ijo37b) - but you should be defining the regex as `/([1-5]+)/` for instance.

Comment: can your string contain other things than 12345, example `215438`, `12345K`...

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte   Ermm, no! I just want 1,2,3,4,5.

Comment: if you want to check only numeric digit..you could use is_numeric() function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If string must contain `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` and `5`, then you should use regex pattern

```
/^(?=.*1)(?=.*2)(?=.*3)(?=.*4)(?=.*5).*/
```

which can be further optimize... for example:

```
/^(?=.*1)(?=.*2)(?=.*3)(?=.*4).*5/
```

---

If no other characters are allowed, then you should use regex pattern

```
/^(?=.*1)(?=.*2)(?=.*3)(?=.*4)(?=.*5)[1-5]*$/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check this with `strpos` as well:

```
<?php
    function str_contains_all($string, $searchValues, $caseSensitive = false) {
        if (!is_array($searchValues)) {
            $searchValues = (string)$searchValues;
            $searchValuesNew = array();
            for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($searchValues); $i++) {
                $searchValuesNew[] = $searchValues[$i];
            }
            $searchValues = $searchValuesNew;
        }

        $searchFunction = ($caseSensitive ? 'strpos' : 'stripos');

        foreach ($searchValues as $searchValue) {
            if ($searchFunction($string, (string)$searchValue) === false) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
?>
```

Use:

```
<?php
    $string = 12345;
    $string2 = 15000;

    if (str_contains_all($string, 12345)) {
        echo 'Y';
        if (str_contains_all($string2, 12345)) {
            echo 'Y';
        } else {
            echo 'N';
        }
    } else {
        echo 'N';
    }
?>
```

Which outputs:

> YN

[**DEMO**](http://codepad.org/eS1Fii9C)