# shorten preg_match(or) code

Tags: regex, preg-match

I was trying to make a program to match the string which must contains number of 0-9 using regex.
This was correct but it somehow seems long. Do anyone has alternatives for this code?

```
if($str = (preg_match('/[1]/', $str) && preg_match('/[2]/', $str)     
  && preg_match('/[3]/', $str) && preg_match('/[4]/', $str)     
  && preg_match('/[5]/', $str) && preg_match('/[6]/', $str)     
  && preg_match('/[7]/', $str) && preg_match('/[8]/', $str)     
  && preg_match('/[9]/', $str) && preg_match('/[0]/', $str))) {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: use /[0-9]/ - that matches "any of the characters in this range".

Comment: I take that back. You want "all of the digits 0 to 9", correct? There is an `&&`, not an `||`, in between your parts of the statements.

Comment: Since your are looking for literal characters, using strpos instead of preg_match will be faster than all regexes possible in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use a character range: `[0-9]`.

```
if (preg_match('/[0-9]/', $str)) {
    echo 'It does.';
} else {
    echo 'It doesn\'t.';
}
```

If you were ever in a situation where you wouldn't want "6" you could even change it to `[012345789]` if you really want to.

---

As [Floris](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1967396/floris) mentions, your code is pretty confusing - if you want all the characters to be displayed individually at least once, you can simply use `strpos` with a loop:

```
<?php
    $match = true;
    for ($i = 0; $i < 9; $i++) {
        if (strpos($string, (string)$i) === false) {
            $match = false;
            break; //No need to continue the loop - we already got our answer
        }
    }

    if ($match) {
        echo 'Yes!';
    } else {
        echo 'No!';
    }
?>
```

[Alternatively, I apparently already gave you a function to do this?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19876317/247893)

Comment: I think your second function is the correct one - and good catch on the earlier answer. Should you mark this as a duplicate?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have all the conditions **ANDed** together. In that following lookahead based regex should work for you:

```
preg_match('/(?=[^0]*0)(?=[^1]*1)(?=[^2]*2)(?=[^3]*3)(?=[^4]*4)(?=[^5]*5)(?=[^6]*6)(?=[^7]*7)(?=[^8]*8)(?=[^9]*9)./', $str)
```

Comment: Yes - but is this really "simpler" than the original solution?

Comment: No I never claimed simpler. But rather than 10 `preg_match` calls it does same in `single preg_match` call.

Comment: @anubhava Completely agree - this does the job - in the way OP wanted it but renders it completely unreadable (such is regex life) when OP in the future looks at it and goes "huh?!". +1 for matching OP's crazy request, though.

Comment: @h2ooooooo: If I'm writing this code I would run a for loop from `0 to 9` and build this regex string rather than hand-coding which will be much more readable and maintainable I guess.

Comment: @anubhava That's actually a good point, however since you're running the `for` loop any way, and might as well use `strpos` or direct equality checking (if OP actually meant `/^[3]$/` etc.)

Comment: @h2ooooooo: Yes I agree.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make sure that your string contains **all** the digits `0-9`, you should probably strip anything that is not a digit, then take unique characters only, and make sure the string length is 10. This is more compact than your expression but not necessarily faster. The [php function `count_chars`](https://www.php.net/count_chars) does much of this work (using `mode = 3`):

```
$str = "12345abcde789d9999969";
preg_match_all('/\d+/', $str, $matches);
$distinct = strlen(count_chars(join($matches[0]),3));
if($distinct==10)
{
  echo "all ten digits are present<br>";
}
else 
{
  echo "not all digits are present<br>";
}
echo "there are " . $distinct . " distinct digits<br>";
```

Output of the above:

```
not all digits are present
there are 9 distinct digits
```